# How to show only one reply form in the blog?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a blog app that allows thread comments. The users can reply to other comments by clicking the "reply" button beside the particular comment. By doing that, a comment form will show up, and the user can type in his reply.

I am using jQuery to build this functionality, here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comment-reply").bind("click.a", function(){

        // hide all forms
        $(".comment-form-reply").hide();

        // bind buttons with "click" events again, because one of them is unbinded
        $(".comment-reply").bind("click.c", function() {
            $(this).parent().siblings(".comment-form-reply").show();
        });

        // show the comment form for current item
        $(this).parent().siblings(".comment-form-reply").show();

        // unbind current button with "click" event to prevent multiple forms
        $(this).unbind(".a");
    });

    $(".comment-reply").bind("click.b", function(){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When I click the first and then the second button, it works well. But if I click the first button again, the two forms are displaying at the same time. I think there should be something wrong here, but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/kqa8z4L4/1/) <- its one way I would do it..just the concept I would do it much cleaner

Comment: Thanks, @Luminous_Dev. I guess I thought about this in a wrong way. As you suggested, I should just hide all forms and show the one needed, rather than unbind the button.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one mistake. You forgot to define "event" as a parameter:

```
$(".comment-reply").bind("click.b", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Right way:**

```
$(".comment-reply").bind("click.b", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You are talking about a reply-button, so I am going to think you are talking about the other buttons with the same class ".comment-reply".

**This example should do exactly what you are looking for with easy code.**

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  
  $(".comment-reply").on("click", evt => { // Use "submit" instead of "click" for form submition !
        // Prevent site from updating (this is only needed for submit-buttons inside a form)
        evt.preventDefault();
        
        // Define varibles
        var elmt          = $(evt.target),
            elmt_sib_c    = elmt.parent().siblings(".comment"),
            elmt_sib_cfr  = elmt.siblings(".comment-form-reply"),
            elmt_sib_exit = elmt.siblings(".comment-form-reply-exit");
        
        if (elmt_sib_cfr.css("display") === "none") {
            
            // Show reply-field
            elmt_sib_cfr.show();
            elmt_sib_exit.show();
        } else if (elmt_sib_cfr.val() != "") {
          // Hide reply-field
          elmt_sib_cfr.hide();
          elmt_sib_exit.hide();
          
          //*//
          console.log(
              "Posted to DB at comment: '",
              elmt_sib_c.text(),
              "' with content of: '",
              elmt_sib_cfr.val(),
              "'"
          );
          //*//
        } else if (elmt_sib_cfr.val() == "") {
            
            elmt_sib_cfr.focus()
        }
        
        // Empty reply-field
        elmt_sib_cfr.val("");
  });
  //
  $(".comment-form-reply-exit").on("click", evt => {
      
      // Define varibles
      var elmt          = $(evt.target),
          elmt_sib_cfr  = elmt.siblings(".comment-form-reply");
      
      function hide () {
          // Hide reply-field
          elmt_sib_cfr.hide();
          elmt.hide();
      }
      
      if (elmt_sib_cfr.val() == "") {
          hide()
      } else if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
          hide()
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.comment-form-reply {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.comment-form-reply-exit {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="comment">This is comment '0'.</div>
  
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="textfield" placeholder="My reply ..." class="comment-form-reply"><button type="button" class="comment-form-reply-exit">Abort</button>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="comment-reply">Reply</button>
  </form>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
  <div class="comment">This is comment '1'.</div>
  
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="textfield" placeholder="My reply ..." class="comment-form-reply"><button type="button" class="comment-form-reply-exit">Abort</button>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="comment-reply">Reply</button>
  </form>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
  <div class="comment">This is comment '2'.</div>
  
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="textfield" placeholder="My reply ..." class="comment-form-reply"><button type="button" class="comment-form-reply-exit">Abort</button>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="comment-reply">Reply</button>
  </form>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
  <div class="comment">This is comment '3'.</div>
  
  <form action="/" method="post">  
    <input type="textfield" placeholder="My reply ..." class="comment-form-reply"><button type="button" class="comment-form-reply-exit">Abort</button>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="comment-reply">Reply</button>
  </form>
</div>
```